# Protractor can't compile Typescript but path exists

Tags: protractor

I'm running the first protractor example in book "Testing Angular Apps" from Manning.
I have fixed some problems in the tsconfig.json but still Typescript won't compile.
The error shown is

```
E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'C:/dev/protractor-examples/primerpt/e2e'.
```

but the path exists.
The example can be found in 
https://github.com/pavitx/protractor-examples, after cloning, go to primerpt directory
run

```
npm install
```

and then

```
npm run e2e protractor-first-test.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chosen values for typescript and ts-node were maybe too new.
Here are the values that work:

```
{
  "name": "protractor-tests",
  "scripts": {
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --gecko false --standalone false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

With these values, the test runs successfully after Typescript "transpilation".